# Is there a way to link static with STL only?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, static-linking

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and write in C++.

My applications should be lightweight; therefore I use `msvcrt.lib` from DDK to link my application with `msvcrt.dll` which exists in any Windows. This trick allows me not to use static linking (libcmt) nor DLL's from MSVC Redistributables; so it reduces size of my executable.

But now I need to use STL in my application. Is there a way to link with some library for STL only? I took `libcpmt.lib` from DDK and tried to link with it; this is what I got:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual char const * __thiscall std::exception::what(void)const " (?what@exception@std@@UBEPBDXZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall std::exception::~exception(void)" (??1exception@std@@UAE@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(char const * const &)" (??0exception@std@@QAE@ABQBD@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(class std::exception const &)" (??0exception@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
```

How can I link my application with `libcpmt.lib` from DDK? How much bytes would be added to executable after linking? Is there another (third-party) STL which is lightweight?

Comment: just fyi tst::exception is not part of the STL, it is part of the c++ standard library.

Comment: I know; but it is in `libcpmt.lib`, isn't it?

Comment: IIRC the STL in MSVC doesn't need linking at all. Having said that, your apps are probably much more heavy than you think. That `msvcrt`you think is cheap? It's on the Microsoft blacklist of things you shouldn't be relying on. When you touch it, your process is automatically suspect. Expect Windows to start its Application Compatibility stuff, to make sure that your outdated application still runs on modern Windows versions (where modern = this century; that MSVCRT dates back to 1998).

Comment: @MSalters the c++ standard library is linked into Visual C++ compiler with flags like [`/MT` or `/MTD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but behind the scenes that still does linking against the runtime library (and adding some defines). If that were not the case you couldn't compile or link things that don't depend on any runtime.

Comment: @PeterT: Stuff like `std::vector<T>` (the STL in the SL) is header-only, that's my point. (Well, you need `operator new` eventually, no way around that)

Comment: @MSalters but it need exceptions as well.

Comment: "`msvcrt.dll` which exists in any Windows" but is non-standard, out-of-date, never updated, possibly insufficient to support newer C++ features, not intended for user-mode applications, ...

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not possible, at least no reliably.  The C++ Standard Library likely depends on the C Standard Library for some functionality, but the unversioned msvcrt.dll you're trying to use is non-standard.